# Windows core 2016 services permissions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-service, windows-server-core

Newly install Windows 2016 Core server, trying to change service startup type.
It seems that default permissions for this service won't let me do it even with domain admin privileges.

```
[servername]PS C:\tmp> subinacl /service "WinHttpAutoProxySvc" /display    
W i n H t t p A u t o P r o x y S v c   -   O p e n S e r v i c e   E r r o r   :   5   A c c e s s   i s   d e n i e d .
```

In Services applet, all properties of the service are greyed out. Other services are also affected.
Is it something to do with Core?

Comment: Is your console is running elevated?

Comment: yes it does. Also the same issue happens when using WinRM. I have deployed a fresh version of  Core and it does not have this issue. Must be something to do with the build .I will update this question if I find what went wrong